# Custom Exception override message with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

If you create a custom Exception that overrides the virtual property `Message` with something like this:

```
public class GrossException : Exception
{
    public GrossException() : base("Eww, gross") { }
}

public class BarfException : GrossException
{
    public override string Message { get; } = "BARF!!";
}
```

Then, when sending `BarfException` using JSON.NET through ASP.NET, the `Message` property will contain

> "Eww, gross"

Instead of the overridden value. I believe this is related to the fact that Exception implements `ISerializable`, but since the `Message` property is virtual, should I not be allowed to override it like this and still have it work?

Is there a proper way to implement Exception and be able to override the `Message` property and still have it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this is happening because `Exception` implements [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) and Json.NET [supports this interface](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#ISerializable).  Specifically, from the reference source, in the method [`Exception.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,549), the `Exception` type serializes the underlying *field*, not the property:

```
        info.AddValue("Message", _message, typeof(String));
```

Microsoft may have done this because the `Message` property has a default value if the underlying field is not set:

```
    public virtual String Message {
           get {  
            if (_message == null) {
                if (_className==null) {
                    _className = GetClassName();
                }
                return Environment.GetResourceString("Exception_WasThrown", _className);

            } else {
                return _message;
            }
        }
    }
```

By serializing the field, not the property, an exception with the default message will have its visible message automatically shown in the `CurrentUICulture` of the receiving system when deserialized.

Thus, if you want the value of the message property to appear in the JSON, instead of the underlying field, you're going to need to override [`GetObjectData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata(v=vs.110).aspx).  And, since [`AddValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akebc4z9(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an exception if you try to add a value with the same name as a pre-existing value, and [`SerializationInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) has no `SetValue()` method to replace a current value, you're going to need to do something with a bit of code smell:

```
public class GrossException : Exception
{
    public GrossException() : base("Eww, gross") { }

    protected GrossException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}

public class BarfException : GrossException
{
    public BarfException() : base() { }

    protected BarfException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    public override string Message { get { return "BARF!!"; } }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var tempInfo = new SerializationInfo(GetType(), new FormatterConverter());
        base.GetObjectData(tempInfo, context);
        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in tempInfo)
        {
            if (entry.Name != "Message")
            {
                info.AddValue(entry.Name, entry.Value, entry.ObjectType);
            }
        }
        info.AddValue("Message", Message);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this solution violates the design of your inheritance hierarchy since the value of the underlying `_message` field is no longer the value *required* by the base class `GrossException`.  But at least the JSON is pretty.

A better solution would be to modify the `GrossException` type to have a protected constructor in which the message can be specified:

```
public class GrossException : Exception
{
    public GrossException() : base("Eww, gross") { }

    protected GrossException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    protected GrossException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

Or, if you just want to *see* the overridden message in the JSON for debugging purposes (say, because you're logging exceptions), you could just add it to the serialization stream like so:

```
public class BarfException : GrossException
{
    public BarfException() : base() { }

    protected BarfException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    public override string Message { get { return "BARF!!"; } }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue("OverriddenMessage", Message);
    }
}
```

Either solution avoids the code smell.